# AWS cognito android development process

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cognito

I'm making an android app that will have users register, log in and upload various types of files to a database. I've been working on the app for about a month and have a very barebones app where users can register and log in and upload photos. I have been hosting a postgres database on my raspberry pi so far, just for testing purposes.

Now I want to move this over to amazon's aws system. Since it's a mobile app I know I will be using a lot of their cognito services. I want to use their new user pools feature and let amazon handle the user registration, log in and authentication for me since it is sure to be more secure than anything I can come up with.

I kind of understand how userpools work and have gone through their tutorials but I'm a little confused as how I can integrate this with the rest of my app structure. Before learning about the cognito service my app was going to have a postgres DB setup using amazon's RDS, an EC2 server where most of my server side scripts would be held (to be called from my android app on the client side when, for example, a user needs to register make a call to register.php) and an S3 instance to store images.

With cognito, I know that some things will probably change. My question is: what will change? Do I and should I still contain a database on amazon's RDS that has all my user's information? What is the best thing to do in this situation?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to access various AWS services once your user has registered and signed in, you will need to integrate your Cognito User Pool into Cognito Federated Identities.

In Cognito Federated Identities, your users acquire credentials based on roles you define. Where you choose to store your users's data is entirely dependent on the logic of your application.

Here is documentation on IAM Roles in Cognito that might be helpful:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html

Here is documentation on how to acquire AWS Credentials for your users:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html